# Toggling visibility of a div in dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, toggle

What is the absolute simplest way to toggle the visibility of a div in dojo, without any fuss.

In jquery I can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mydiv").hide();        
  $("#link-that-toggles-div").click(function()       
  {          
     $("#mydiv").slideToggle();          
  });
}

...

<a href="#" target="_self" id="link-that-toggles-div">Toggle the div</a>
<div id="mydiv">Awesome content</div>
```

Is there any equivalent thing in dojo? Or do I have to roll my own? dojo.fx.Toggler for instance, forces me to manually do the show/hide, instead of simply giving me a toggle() function. Also, all the examples uses one button for showing the div, and another for hiding it, I'm not sure why it's even called Toggler in such a case.

Comment: check here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/fx/Toggler.html

Comment: As I tried to mention in the question, I'm aware of the Toggler class, but I find it lacking and reproducing the equivalent jquery code isn't exactly straight forward. For instance, I want the same button to toggle between showing and hiding the div. All the examples for the Toggler class uses 2 buttons. Do I really need to write my own code to check if the div is hidden, and in that case do show() and vice versa for hide? Why is it even called Toggler in that case? If I have to implement all the toggle logic myself.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy example how you can use one Button for both: toggleIn/toggleOut.

```
require(["dojo/fx/Toggler", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(Toggler, dom, on){
var isClicked = false;
var toggler = new Toggler({
node: "basicNode"
});
 on(dom.byId("toggleButton"), "click", function(e){
    if(isClicked===false){
       toggler.hide();
      isClicked=true;
  }
  else{
      toggler.show();
      isClicked=false;
  }
 });
});
```

With the Variable "isClicked" you can change which toggle you want to use.

Here's the fiddle for the Example above:
http://jsfiddle.net/XLAFz/

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Thank you for the code example. I was hoping I didn't have to implement all this logic on my own, and having something more like the jQuery example.

Comment: Okay - it's not one function for all, but it's a nice small one without any extraordinary or complicated twists. I have used one Button and just change the called functions with the help of the variable. I do not know much about jquery, but sadly there seems to be no other way to handle a toggle in dojo.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(dom, domClass, on){
        on(dom.byId("ID"), "click", function(){
            domClass.contains("ID", "hide")? domClass.replace("ID", "display", "hide"):         
                                             domClass.replace("ID", "hide", "display");
    }); 
});

/* .hide{display:none} .display{display: block} */
```

Comment: domClass has a `toggle` function.